# TortoiseSVN: How to get a list of all revisions that update files in specific directories

Tags: java, windows, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

Say I have a project with the following structure:

```
Some-Project
> src
> inputs
> outputs
> docs
> libs
```

How can I get a list of all SVN revisions where updates are made to any code files in 'src' or any input files in 'inputs' using TortoiseSVN if possible?

The only thing I can think of is to go into the 'src' and 'input' folders individually then use TortoiseSVN -> Show Log and then manually tally up the revisions but that is very inefficient.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you share it with us?

Comment: Here's a useful link about SVNKit https://wiki.svnkit.com/Getting_Started_With_SVNKit

Comment: @hfontanez i added to the description my current idea

Comment: @bahrep I would agree that it might not be necessary, but _absolutely irrelevant_ doesn't seem to be right. You could use it to obtain that same information programmatically rather than manually. But, I digress.

Comment: @hfontanez now I think that you are right. I've just removed that comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you open the [Revision Log](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html) dialog for `src` or `inputs` you will only see the commits that touched contents of these directories. The same applies to running [`svn log`](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html).